# What is the difference between Copy Bundle Resources and Copy Files for Xcode build phases?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

Could someone explain the difference between the `Copy Bundle Resources` phase of Xcode and a `Copy Files` phase? When would I use "Copy Files"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Copy Bundle Resources` phase copies files that you want to be available in your bundle (.app). On the other hand `Copy Files` phase copies files to other (standard) locations accessible from your application (for example to /Library/Fonts) giving you also the option to copy them only when installing. You can also see [relevant documentation here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/10.2/#/dev50bab713d)

Comment: Thanks. Is this not relevant to iOS products then? Seems like with iOS everything would have to go in the bundle.

Comment: No it is not ios specific and yes the most common scenario I can think of for ios would be to copy files into the bundle.

Comment: @AndrewKoster  Thanks for that. I have updated the link

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode Copy Files vs Copy Bundle Resources**

`Copy Files` - Copies files from a project to an **external** specified location.

[image]    [image]

It is useful, for example, when you are creating an Objective-C `Static Library` where you should expose `.modulemap`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57665560/4770877) or/and `umbrella.h`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57481319/4770877) files

`Copy Bundle Resources` - Copies files that support your source code into **internal** structure. If you want to make sure the files you added will get copied to the application bundle

[image]     [image]

It is useful, when you are creating an `app` where you can add images and other resources

[Vocablurary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)