# What's the difference between "Copy Bundle Resources" and "Copy Files" -> "Resources"

Tags: xcode, macos, resources

Xcode has the special *Build Phase* **Copy Bundle Resources** as well as the more general **Copy Files**. When I set the *Destination* of the latter to **Resources**, I can't spot any difference in behaviour, the listed files are copied to `Contents/Resources` in both cases.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11164042/) says **Copy Files** is more powerful and can do other locations as well, but still I don't see the point why one should use **Copy Bundle Resources** at all. Does it do something special that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Copy Bundle Resources** phase does indeed some additional work:

- Images in an `.iconset` folder (usually for several resolutions) are converted to a single `.icns` file (as with the `iconutil -c icns` command).
- *Property lists* and are converted according to the `PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT` build setting.
- `.strings` files are converted according to the `STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING` build setting.

And maybe there are more conversions for other file formats... Those are just the ones I found by trial and error.

PS: `PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT` and `STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING` can be enforced in the **Copy Files** phase by setting `APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES` to `true`. But this does not work for the iconset conversion.